# PHP preg_match_all get name of variable between short tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have template files which use short tags `<?= $some_var; ?>`. I need to write a script to get a list of the variables used in that template, i.e. an array like:

```
[
    0 => '$some_var',
    ...
    n => '$some_var_n'
]
```

I have tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<?[^p](.*)?>/s', $file_contents, $matches);
```

and some other various combinations but to no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/<?=[^p](.*)?>/s', $file_contents, $matches);` or `preg_match_all('/<?=(.*)?>/s', $file_contents, $matches);`

Comment: Yes, @chris85 it's only ever variables.

Comment: @AlivetoDie The `?`s need to be escaped.

Comment: Works great for me, @chris85 thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `?`s, otherwise they make the preceding character/group optional. You also can make the regex stricter and use the regex for valid variable names PHP provides(http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php).

Something like:

```
<\?=\h+(\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]+);?\h*\?>
```

should find your variables.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/fVBZAS/1/

Answer (score 1):

With [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php):

```
function genTempVar($text) {
    $open = false;
    foreach (token_get_all($text) as $v) {
        if ( $open ) {
            if ( $v[0] == T_CLOSE_TAG ) $open = false;
            elseif ( $v[0] == T_VARIABLE ) yield $v[1];
        } elseif ( $v[0] == T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO ) $open = true; 
    }
} 

print_r(iterator_to_array(genTempVar($text)));
```